# Why we say that electrical energy is power over time p x t?

Tags: energy, time, work, potential-energy, power

How electrical energy can be power over time when electrical energy is actually potential energy?

from a lot of sources (wiki ,study.com..) comes the information that electric energy is potential or kinetic energy. In other sources is said to be electric power p x t so i am confused by this if anyone could explain to me what was right.

Comment: Power is simply the rate of energy *transfer*.  It tells you how fast energy is being stored or used.  It doesn't say anything about *where* that energy is stored or used.

Comment: It is not power *over* time, but power *times* time

Comment: whether you want a monument for this statement

Comment: if you look carefully you will notice this  p x t

Comment: @igrabrza You have written the words: »*power over time*« in the first sentence...

Comment: igra brza daj se skuliraj....definicija snage je brzina prijenosa energije iliti energija kroz vrijeme, a ti si napisao power OVER time što je zbunjujuće.

Comment: -1 Not clear what your difficulty is. What is the conflict in your mind between kinetic or potential energy and power x time?

Comment: Žarko Tomičić .  Tko ovdje priča o snazi daj budi ljubazan pa čitaj pitanje i nemojte tražit dlaku u jajetu poanta je jasno vidljiva za one koji žele odgovoriti i naravno znaju odgovorit. skuliran sam s normalnim ljudima  ne cjepidlakama.Hvala na tvom vremenu

Answer (score 1):

As in many other situations you will find, there are a lot of different approaches to understand a basic fact, or sort of "lenses" you can see it through.

In your case the basic fact is this: when you look at electromagnetism through a very powerful lens that you have not been taught yet (the lens of "action principles" and "Lagrangians"), you can see that (a) you *can* use this lens correctly to determine the "rules" of electromagnetism, and (b) when you do, the rules of electromagnetism do not change over time. This lens then says, "If the rules exist and do not change over time, there is a number which you can calculate for the whole system, which also does not change over time." We call this number the *total energy*. Very often it breaks up into a lot of nice separate terms, for example very often we see a term $\frac12 m v^2$ for a particle of mass $m$ moving with speed $v$, and we call it the "kinetic energy of that particle." If you want to increase this particle's speed, and therefore increase the contribution of this one term to the total energy, but you cannot change the total energy, then some other term must *decrease* in energy. The terms that exist even when nothing is moving are contributions that we call "potential energy" terms.

There are other things which are harder to see through this lens. For example, you may know that energy is not conserved by friction; this lens says "it is very hard to determine the rules of friction." If you learn more you will learn that it is not so difficult, but you need to include an infinity of little places that the energy can escape to, if you want to understand friction through this lens. (This is not as bad as it sounds because all those little places also help to define temperature, and explain why all of the air in the atmosphere doesn't fall to the ground like bigger objects like rocks and pianos do.)

But there are other perspectives to come to this "energy picture" from, and one of them is called "power flows". This says that we have a particle at position $\mathbf r_i$ experiencing a bunch of forces $\mathbf F_i$, and we know that there are the Newton's laws relating the acceleration (second derivative of position with respect to time, or $\ddot{\mathbf r}$) to the particle mass $m$ and all of these forces on them, by the vector sum$$m~\ddot{\mathbf r} = \sum_i \mathbf F_i.$$ We define the power flowing from some force into the particle as the dot product with the particle's velocity, $P_i = \mathbf F_i \cdot \dot{\mathbf r}.$ So if the force is perpendicular to the motion, no power flows into the particle; if the force is along the motion, power flows in; if the force is against the motion, power flows out as this product becomes negative.

Newton's equations then say, $$m~\ddot {\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r} = \sum_i P_i.$$ The right hand side is the net power flow; the left hand side is quickly seen to be a total derivative: $$\frac{d}{dt} (\dot{\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r}) = \ddot{\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r} + \dot{\mathbf r}\cdot\ddot{\mathbf r} = 2 \ddot{\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r}.$$ Assuming the mass isn't changing over time we can rewrite this as, $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 ~m ~\dot{\mathbf r}\cdot\dot{\mathbf r}\right) = \sum_i P_i.$$ On the left hand side we see the time derivative of this "kinetic energy term" we were talking about earlier: the net power flow changes kinetic energy.

Which brings us back to your question, don't these power changes come from potential energy terms ultimately? Yes! Of course they do. Potential energy terms are seen through this lens as those forces. Mathematically, we have that there is this potential energy function $U(\mathbf r)$ that assigns this potential-energy term to each position; and the gradient of this potential energy gives the force, $\mathbf F = -\nabla U.$ When we form this dot product $-\nabla U \cdot \dot{\mathbf r}$, we can recognize that this, too, is a total time derivative. Here it helps to look at it in terms of its components; the tangent plane approximation to the potential energy function now looks like $$U(x + v_x~dt, y + v_y~dt, z + v_z~dt) \approx U(x, y, z) + {\partial U\over\partial x}~v_x~dt + {\partial U\over\partial y}~v_y~dt + {\partial U\over\partial z}~v_z~dt,$$ which rearranges nicely to $$
{U(\mathbf r + \dot{\mathbf r}~dt) - U(\mathbf r)\over dt} \approx \nabla U \cdot \dot{\mathbf r}.$$ Hence we find that for power flows which come from potential energies, $$P_i = -\frac{dU_i}{dt}.$$If those are the only power flows then we have $$\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac12 m v^2\right) = -\frac{d}{dt}\left(\sum_i U_i\right),$$ and we find a statement of energy conservation again: $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12 m v^2 + \sum_i U_i\right) = 0.$$ It's just a different way to get to the same "energy picture" that you can hopefully understand without me explaining "action principles" and "Lagrangians" to you: it is a different way of looking at the "forces" that so intrigued Newton, which gets us back to this "energy picture" by asking about these time-rate-of-energy-flows, or power-flows,  that are created by these forces.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are simply overthinking the term *power*.

Power just means **energy per second**. That's all. It can be any kind of energy.

For instance, if a ball falls from a shelf, then potential energy decreases. A certain amount of potential energy is removed every second. (Converted into kinetic energy.) This could be called power.

The loss in electrical potential energy every second as charges move through a resistor can also be called power.

And since this lost potential energy is transfered into heat and light in the filament of a light bulb, the term power is very useful there.